# Constructing Map from Set<Map.Entry> in Java 7?

Tags: java

`java.util.Map` comes with [entrySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) method that...

> Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map.

Is there a single method call or a series of API calls to reconstruct a set out of the set using the Java 7 API as marked *what do I need to put here?* in the following code sample?

```
package so;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class SetMapExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
        m.put("k1", "v1");
        m.put("k2", "v2");
        Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> s = m.entrySet();
        Map<String, String> ms = s...   // what do I need to put here?
    }
}
```

I don't want to use `for` loop if possible and expect a similar method to `entrySet` on `Map`, but I can't seem to find one.

Comment: `for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : s) { ms.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()); }`...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza please dont offer answers as comments.

Comment: Note: a `Set` uses a Map behind the scenes and the *values* in the `Set` are in fact keys in the `Map`. So, it is not possible to accomplish what you want/need without a `for` loop.

Comment: @paul.cioroianu OP clearly states that he/she doesn't want to use a `for` loop. Also, you can copy the content in comments and turn it into an answer if you feel like that.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it may be that case, but the content of your two comments adds up to a good answer I believe. Comments are meant for clarifications to the question and answers are for answering. It is not good ethics to get the content of another user's comments and post an answer with it.

Comment: This could make an interesting meta post. I frequently post trivial answers as comments if either I'm not sure what the OP really wants or I don't think it's worth a "real" answer.

Comment: @chrylis at last, somebody thinks similar to me...

Comment: Why are carrying a Set of Map:Entry around? Why not simply using new `Map newMap = HashMap<Key, Value>(); newMap.putAll(oldMap);` ?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but I will say that such a method would not be sound in the general case.  `Map.Entry` computes [equality](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) based on the key AND the value.  So contrary to intuition, you could easily have a `Set<Map.Entry>` that contains two bindings for the same key, meaning a `Set<Map.Entry>` is no more an alternate representation of a `Map` than a `List<Map.Entry>` is.  It's only the contract of `Map` that makes `entrySet()` not have multiple bindings for one key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Commons Collections provides [`MapUtils.putAll`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MapUtils.html#putAll%28java.util.Map,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) which can do what you want, but under the covers that just does the `for` loop logic that you want to avoid, so you might as well just do the looping yourself...

In general there's no way to construct a `Map` out of a `Set` of entries that won't require you (or the library function you are calling) to iterate over the entries at least once - there might be special cases, e.g. if you have a list of entries that you know are sorted by key then you could write a read-only map implementation on top of that that uses binary search to find the key.

Comment: That is one bizarre method.  It does two different things depending on what interfaces the first element of the passed-in `Object[]` implements.  It feels like a function I'd find in Javascript code, or some other dynamically typed language.  But kudos for finding a library method that is close to what the OP wants.

Comment: @MarkPeters it is a bit of a bizzarre one, in a Java library I'd have expected overloads for `Map.Entry[]`, `Object[][]`, etc. instead of runtime dynamic typing.

Answer (score 1):

A `Set` uses a `Map` behind the scenes and the *values* in the `Set` are in fact keys in the `Map`. So, it is not possible to accomplish what you want/need without a `for` loop. Using plain Java (no other fancy frameworks), you only can do this:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : s) {
    ms.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: What about a case where I had `Set<Map.Entry<String,String>>` as if it was passed me? I only offered the `main` sample in the question as a guidance in case I'm not clear about my intention.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I don't understand your question, but my answer still says that you cannot do it without using a `for` loop.

Comment: I was just saying that in my case I was given the `Set` and although it's backed by `Map` I don't have access to it. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

JDK does not provide such method, however you can use Guava if you want. Tip: use `Transofrmers` or `Maps`. You have to write your own "transformer" - one-line implementation of Guava's `Function`. If you implement it as generic top level class you can re-use it later.

Comment: Which transform method do you suggest using?  Transforming between data types is not what Guava `transform` methods do, they transform the *entries* of a data structure while maintaining the same data type.  So to use Guava here, you need to point to which method will convert between a `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>` and a `Map<K, V>`

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Map#entrySet()` is a one-view operation concerning addition of elements and a constructor accepting a `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>>` seems a very specific and seldom happening case.